# Proper implementation of a basic COM object in MFC: should CCmdTarget be used?

Tags: c++, mfc, com

I need to extend an old C++ project which uses COM and MFC. I worked with C++/COM before but it was years ago. I see that all COM interfaces implementations in the project inherit CCmdTarget. Even the ones which are not used for UI tasks but just transfer data to methods. Surely CCmdTarget does implement all necessary stuff for COM but it looks like it contains a lot more which is not needed: like wait cursor support and message processing. This is not needed for simple interfaces. Isn't there a more lightweight way to implement them? Or is it a common practice to use CCmdTarget as a base object for all MFC COM implementations?

Comment: You would need to make the jump to ATL based COM.  It is completely compatible with MFC based COM but exposes a more raw interface to COM.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks! This was my first idea as ATL is what I used when I worked with COM. But providing I want to keep the project changes minimal is CCmdTarget the only choice? I guess so...